# Spring boot 2.6.7 incompatibility with spring-cloud-context 3.1.1, CVE-2022-22965

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We want to upgrade spring boot to 2.6.7 to address CVE-2022-22965.  That requires spring-cloud 2021.0.1, which includes spring-cloud-context 3.1.1 (the newest version).  That group of modules causes the following runtime error:

```
Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to following reasons:

- Spring Boot [2.6.7] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train


Action:

Consider applying the following actions:

- Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [2.2.x, 2.3.x] .
```

Also, spring-cloud-context is flagged in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context/3.1.1)
as vulnerable to CVE-2022-22965, which we are trying to remediate.

Omitting spring-cloud-context causes the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans'
  defined in class path resource
[org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]:
  Post-processing of merged bean definition failed;
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  Failed to introspect Class
[org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]
  from ClassLoader
  [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@3d646c37]
```

What version of spring-cloud-config should be used, or when will a new version be available?
Links for how we arrived at this combination:

- [Spring Boot 2.6.6 available now](https://spring.io/blog/2022/03/31/spring-boot-2-6-6-available-now),
  which we upgraded to 2.6.7
- [Spring Cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud),
  which specifies release train 2021.0.x for boot 2.6.x
- MVN Repository for [spring-cloud-dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies)
  indicates [2021.0.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2021.0.1)
  is the latest version of the 2021.0.x release train.
- Dependencies 2021.0.1 includes [spring-cloud-context](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context)
  version 3.1.1, which appears to be the latest version available,
  searching both MVN Repository and
  [Sonatype](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context).

For full context, our application uses the following spring packages:

- spring-boot-starter-parent, 2.6.7

  - spring-boot-starter
  - spring-boot-actuator
  - spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure
  - spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config, 1.1.10.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-context, 3.1.1

Comment: Looks like you have an older version of spring cloud context. Can you provide your calculated dependencies?

Comment: @spencergibb: I added links to the original post, showinng how we arrived at the spring package versions.  I believe we're using the latest spring-cloud-context.  If a newer one is available, can you provide a repository link?  Thanks.

Comment: I know that the latest spring cloud context doesn't say boot 2.2.x, 2.3.x is the compatible version. Spring Cloud Kubernetes 1.x is not compatible with spring cloud 2021.0

Answer (score 2):

Just Change your Spring Cloud version to 2021.0.1 in --> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2021.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: We are using Spring Cloud 2021.0.1 already, and in fact updated it to 2021.0.2, which has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using 3.1.0 for org.springframework.cloud.
For me this error got resolved but some of my test cases are failing